# Getting image from WEB-INF folder

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I trie to get an image from my image folder which is placed in the WEB-INF.
But i get the NullPointerException.

```
   Image logo = Image.getInstance(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/img/auditweb.png"));
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

Have change the code as suggested

```
Image logo = Image.getInstance(this.getClass().getResource("/WEB-INF/resources/img/auditweb.png"));
```

But didn't work

Comment: try: ....getResource("/WEB-INF/resources/img/auditweb.png"));

Comment: Start your path with WEB-INF?

Comment: Also didn't work

Comment: WEB-INF is not in the classpath. You can't load a resource that is located there with the ClassLoader, which looks into the classpath. You need to use ServletContext.getResource(), or to put the images undere WEB-INF/classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

neither the root folder of your webapp, not WEB-INF, are in the classpath. You thus can't load a resource that is located there with the ClassLoader, which looks into the classpath.

You need to use [`ServletContext.getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource-java.lang.String-), or to put the images undere `WEB-INF/classes`.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting `NullPointerException` because you are providing the wrong path.

```
Image logo = Image.getInstance(this.getClass().getResource("/WEB-INF/resources/img/auditweb.png"));
                                                             /\
                                                             ||
                                                             ||
                                                             ||
                        Path should start with WEB-INF  ------
```